# Allow data to delete from one table to add to another table

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access, ms-access-2016, inventory

I have posted about this table and form multiple times and I know I shouldn't do it this way. I am having trouble with my code. I need for when the ToGo hits 0 then the row on the WorkOrders table moves to the Done WorkOrders table and then deletes out of the WorkOrders table. The code I had before was

```
Private Sub ItemCode_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set DB = CurrentDb

Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("Select ToGo from WorkOrders where ItemCode =" & Me.ItemCode)

With rs
    .Edit
    !ToGo = !ToGo - 1
    .Update
    .Edit
    
End With

End Sub
```

This was just making my code decrease by 1 every scan. So, I added the rest of the code to do the switch to a different table and then delete, but now my ToGo won't decrease at all. This is the updated code I have now with the if statement.

```
Private Sub ItemCode_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim rsOld As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsNew As DAO.Recordset

Set DB = CurrentDb

Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("Select ToGo from WorkOrders where ItemCode =" & Me.ItemCode)
Set rsNew = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM WorkOrders")
Set rsOld = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from WorkOrders where ItemCode =" & Me.ItemCode)

If ToGo > 0 Then
    With rs
        .Edit
        !ToGo = !ToGo - 1
        .Update
        .Edit
    
    End With
Else
    rsNew.AddNew
    For i = 0 To rsOld.Fields.Count - 1
    rsNew.Fields(i).Value = rsOld.Fields(i).Value
    Next
    rsNew.Update
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM WorkOrders WHERE ItemCode= & Me.ItemCode
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    rsNew.Close
    rsOld.Close
    Set rsNew = Nothing
    Set rsOld = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Can someone let me know if this is even possible.

Comment: Why 'move' records? Just change value in a field that will indicate change in status.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: This site is so awesome on giving answers. Every post I have posted someone replies then I give them the answer to their question then they just not answer back. Maybe answer back with what else you need or it's not possible.

Comment: Actually, you seem to already have a status field. ToGo is field in table and when it is set as 0, work order is done. "Moving" records is an unnecessary complication to data structure.

Comment: So lets not move records. Lets just have the record move forward. Can I do a if statement to say 'If ToGo > 0 Then .Update Else .MoveNext'?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'moving' records between tables, change record status with edit in a field. You seem to already have a field that indicates a work order is 'done' - the ToGo field. Consider:

```
With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
        If !ToGo = 0 Then
           .MoveNext
        End If
        .Edit
        !ToGo = !ToGo - 1
        .Update
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Okay there were no errors, but I am using DLookup in control source so its showing the current. How could I get WrkOrdNum and ToGo in the code to allow for it to work through the records?

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand that. Probably because I just don't know enough about your db design. So answer does not resolve issue?

Comment: Okay so you know how the DLookup works in the control source right?

Comment: Yes, I know the domain aggregate functions. If form is bound to WorkOrders and ToGo field is in WorkOrders, why would you need DLookup()? In fact what you are doing could probably be done directly with records on form instead of recordset. Or maybe should use form's RecordsetClone. Edit to data in RecordsetClone is immediately reflected in form.